# nodejs multer file upload, what happens file names are the same from 2 places

Tags: node.js, multer

The concept is still not clear to me yet.
For a very basic case, i can upload a file (say myFile.txt) using multer, and keep its original name in the server side.

```
const upload = multer({ dest: `${UPLOAD_PATH}/` }); // multer configuration
```

Now another person happen to upload a different file with same file name myFile.txt to the same folder in server side. Will it overwrite the previous one ?

How do you normally manage this ? Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

> Will it overwrite the previous one ?

Yes it will definitely replace with the new one.Here is my code .In this code if you use a same file name from different locations or from the same location it won't replaces.It keeps both the files in destination.Server code `server.js`

```
var express=require('express');
var multer=require('multer');
var path = require('path')
var app=express();
var ejs = require('ejs')
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, './public/uploads')
    },
    filename: function(req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname))
        //callback(null, file.originalname)
    }
})

app.get('/api/file',function(req,res){
res.render('index');
});
app.post('/api/file', function(req, res) {
    var upload = multer({
        storage: storage}).single('userFile');
    upload(req, res, function(err) {
        console.log("File uploaded");
        res.end('File is uploaded')
    })
})

app.listen(3000,function(){
console.log("working on port 3000");
});
```

If you observe the code  `callback(null, file.originalname)` this line will keep the original file name in destination and will replace the file when it gets the same name.If you don't want this then use `callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname))`.This callback changes the name of file in destination.

Make a views folder and keep this file in it.ejs code from which you can choose a file to upload `index.ejs`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <input type="file" name="userFile" />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Run the code as node `server.js`.Open the browser and type `http://localhost:3000/api/file`.Choose a file to upload and see the destination folder.Hope this helps for you.

Comment: ok, so you use timestamp to manage this case, it works, thank you :). I wait a little bit to see if others have other ways.

Comment: Atleast you can make upvote as this helps for you....and you can accept later based on others answers

Answer (score 3):

actually Multer saves the file in a given path (as specied by you) but with a different randomised filename. It will not override the file even if the name of the file is the same. 
So your UPLOAD_PATH will have multiple files even if you are loading the the file with same name again.

Answer (score 0):

You can go a step further to ensure the file names are *more specific*:

```
filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    let fn = file.originalname.split(path.extname(file.originalname))[0] + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname);
    cb(null, /* file.originalname */ fn);
}
```