# How to upload file using Koa.JS 2?

Tags: node.js, file-upload, upload, koa, koa2

How to upload file using Koa.JS 2? I tried using koa.js but I was not getting the file in the `ctx` object.

Answer (score 1):

these are ur best options

[async-busboy](https://github.com/m4nuC/async-busboy)

[@koa/multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@koa/multer)

@koa/multer example:

```
import Router from 'koa-router';
import multer from '@koa-multer';

const router = new Router();

const upload = multer({
 storage: multer.memoryStorage()
});

router.post('/upload', upload.single('document'), async ctx => {
const { file } = ctx.req;

// Do stuff with the file here

ctx.status = 200;
});
```

[source](http://www.johnduhamel.io/posts/2016-08-11-direct-s3-upload.html)

try to do some validation before upload (change name if file exists) - partial example code:

```
let storage = multer.diskStorage({
 destination: function(req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, './public/uploads')
 },
 filename: function(req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + 
 path.extname(file.originalname))
    //callback(null, file.originalname)
 }
})

app.post('/api/file', function(req, res) {
var upload = multer({
    storage: storage}).single('userFile');
upload(req, res, function(err) {
    console.log("File uploaded");
    res.end('File is uploaded')
})
})
```

[example source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45776060/nodejs-multer-file-upload-what-happens-file-names-are-the-same-from-2-places)

Comment: koa-multer is not returning me which file it uploaded. How will I get the file or the content of the file that it uploaded?

Comment: i added an example and source to my answer, let me know if it works for u

Comment: When I use your given code, the API call exists before `// Do stuff with the file here` is completed the execution. It seems to be existing from `upload.single('document')`

Comment: updated my answer with a validation / change name example
try to name the file as timestamp to avoid duplication